# determine signal frequency and phase

Tags: trigonometry

let us consider following graph

[image]

we should  answer on the following question

**In the following figure, it is possible to measure both a positive and a negative value of $t_1$ and then calculate the corresponding phase shifts. 
    Which phase shift is within the range $-π < Ø < π   ?$ Verify that the two phase shifts differ by 2π.**

now from this graph we should determine period,graph it is repeating it's phase at $0.005$ 
 that means that period is distance between them or $0.025$,

so frequency is  $1/T=40$  now for phase we should find $2*\pi*40*0.005+\phi=0$  or  $\phi=-0.4*pi$

there is another value which will be

$2*\pi*40*-0.02+\phi=0$ or $\phi=1.6$  so difference between them is  $2*\pi$
am i right?

Comment: Probably you should separate the original questions (exactly as stated) by your comments. In the present form I have some difficulties to understand what is asked.

Comment: i have  made bold color for question